# File Reading to get Revenue in 2ND Column

Tags: c#, streamreader

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Faran\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\cast.csv");
        StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Faran\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\actors.csv");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Faran\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\directorRevenue.csv");
        string line = null,line1 = null;
        bool chk = false;
        string[] token = null;
        string output = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            output = null;
            chk = false;
            token = line.Split(',');
            while ((line1 = reader1.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                chk = false;
                var token1 = line1.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < token.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (token[i].Contains(token1[0]) || token1[0].Contains(token[i]) || token[i] == token1[0])
                    {
                        chk = true;
                        output = token[i] + "," + token1[1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteLine(output);
        }
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        reader1.Close();
```

"
Read from 1 File "CAST" and find the TOKEN[i] in the "ACTORS" file to get its Revenue.

ACTORS FILE

Amy Adams,  2126

Ben Affleck,    2288.8

Casey Affleck,  911.5

Dianna Agron,   131.6

Jessica Alba,   952.3

Alan Alda,  753

Joan Allen, 854.3

Tim Allen,  1763

Woody Allen,    461.3

Mathieu Amalric,    300.7

Gillian Anderson,   146.4

Julie Andrews,  925.6

Jennifer Aniston,   1627.1

Aziz Ansari,    168.6

CAST FILE

Amy Adams, Alex Descas

Ben Affleck, Melina Matthews

Jaenada, Casey Affleck

Bulent Dincer, Dianna Agron

Sarah Steele, Jessica Alba

Jerome Ro Brooks, Alan Alda
"

Comment: it returns single answer while I need all of the cast with revenue

Comment: done as 2nd time while loop starts the reader from endOfFile that's why the next value was not found
so add before 2nd while

reader1.DiscardBufferedData();

reader1.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);